# TSQL - Aggregates in HAVING Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, where-clause

I know this problem has been asked a lot but when I address the error message and use a HAVING clause, I am still receiving the dreaded:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a 
subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, 
and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

**What am I doing wrong, here?**

```
SELECT
mr.ClubKeyNumber,
COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID),
SUM(CONVERT(int,mr.Submitted))
FROM MonthlyReport mr
WHERE mr.ReportYear = 2014
AND COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID) = 12
GROUP BY mr.ClubKeyNumber
HAVING (SUM(CONVERT(int,mr.Submitted))) > 11
```

Comment: You probably want to move this predicate `COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID) = 12` to the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: `AND COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID) = 12` add it to Having Clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't with your `HAVING` clause it's in your `WHERE` clause.

You have an aggregate `count` in your `where` clause, try this:

```
SELECT
mr.ClubKeyNumber,
COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID),
SUM(CONVERT(int,mr.Submitted))
FROM MonthlyReport mr
WHERE mr.ReportYear = 2014
GROUP BY mr.ClubKeyNumber
HAVING (SUM(CONVERT(int,mr.Submitted))) > 11 and COUNT(mr.MonthlyReportID) = 12
```

The `where` clause checks each row being aggregated before the `group by` clause.  It cannot `count` your `MonthlyReportID` until *after* the `group by` so move it to the `having clause`.

[Here is a simple example](http://rextester.com/RBU48764) you can play with to demonstrate where vs have.